# Search Data from Object By Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, search

I'm having a little trouble searching data in an array object and displaying it.

I have a people JSON object, as you can see from the snippet below.

I can load all the people, but how do I show the person that when I enter the name in the input and the other people hide? Here's what I'm doing:

```js
const people = [{
    "name": "Messi",
    "age": 34
  },
  {
    "name": "Pedri",
    "age": 18
  },
  {
    "name": "Ronaldo",
    "age": 37
  }
];

function loadData() {
  people.forEach(function(person) {
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    $(container).addClass('person');

    const name = document.createElement('p');
    const age = document.createElement('p');

    $(name).addClass('name');
    $(age).addClass('age');

    name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(person["name"]));
    age.appendChild(document.createTextNode(person["age"]));

    container.appendChild(name);
    container.appendChild(age);

    document.getElementById('people').appendChild(container);
  })
}

function searchData(query) {

}

loadData();

window.onload = () => {
  const search = document.getElementById('search');
  search.onkeyup = () => {
    searchData(search.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input id="search" type="text" name="" value="">
    <div id="people" class="people">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified code, with case-insensitive search may be like this one:

```js
const people = [{
    "name": "Messi",
    "age": 34
  },
  {
    "name": "Pedri",
    "age": 18
  },
  {
    "name": "Ronaldo",
    "age": 37
  }
];
var searchInput = $('#search');
var peopleDiv = $('#people');
function loadData(q = '') {
  var peopleHtml = '';
  $.each(people, function(p, person) {
    if (person.name.toLowerCase().includes(q.toLowerCase())) {
      peopleHtml += '<div class="person">' + person.name + ': ' + person.age + '</div>';
    };
  });
  peopleDiv.html(peopleHtml);
}
searchInput.on('input', function(e) {
  loadData($(this).val());
});
loadData();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input id="search" type="text" name="" value="">
  <div id="people" class="people"></div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/e3v7tu1z/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter

```js
people.filter(person=> person.name === query)
```

or if you need only one you can use find

```js
people.find(person=> person.name === query)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully but you can do it like that. )

```js
const people = [
  {
    "name":"Messi",
    "age":34
  },
  {
    "name":"Pedri",
    "age":18
  },
  {
    "name":"Ronaldo",
    "age":37
  }
];

function loadData() {
  people.forEach(function(person) {
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    $(container).addClass('person');

    const name = document.createElement('p');
    const age = document.createElement('p');

    $(name).addClass('name');
    $(age).addClass('age');

    name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(person["name"]));
    age.appendChild(document.createTextNode(person["age"]));

    container.appendChild(name);
    container.appendChild(age);

    document.getElementById('people').appendChild(container);
  })
}

function searchData(query) {
  people.forEach(function(person) {  
    if(query == person['name']){
     $('#people').empty();
    
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    $(container).addClass('person');

    const name = document.createElement('p');
    const age = document.createElement('p');

    $(name).addClass('name');
    $(age).addClass('age');

    name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(person["name"]));
    age.appendChild(document.createTextNode(person["age"]));

    container.appendChild(name);
    container.appendChild(age);

    document.getElementById('people').appendChild(container);
  }
});
};

loadData();

window.onload = () => {
  const search = document.getElementById('search');
  search.onkeyup = () => {
    searchData(search.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <input id="search" type="text" name="" value="">

    <div id="people" class="people">

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet removes dynamically the names which are not included in the query written in the input field

```js
const people = [{
    "name": "Messi",
    "age": 34
  },
  {
    "name": "Pedri",
    "age": 18
  },
  {
    "name": "Ronaldo",
    "age": 37
  }
];

function loadData() {
  people.forEach(function(person) {
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    $(container).addClass('person');
    $(container).attr('name', person['name']);
    $(container).attr('hidden', true);

    const name = document.createElement('p');
    const age = document.createElement('p');

    $(name).addClass('name');
    $(age).addClass('age');

    name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(person["name"]));
    age.appendChild(document.createTextNode(person["age"]));

    container.appendChild(name);
    container.appendChild(age);

    document.getElementById('people').appendChild(container);
  })
}

function searchData(query) {

  const people = document.getElementsByClassName('person');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    name = people[i].getAttribute('name').toLowerCase();
        
    if (query.length > 0 && name.includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
      people[i].removeAttribute('hidden');
    } else {
        people[i].setAttribute('hidden', true);
    }
  }
}

loadData();

window.onload = () => {
  const search = document.getElementById('search');
  search.onkeyup = () => {
    searchData(search.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input id="search" type="text" name="" value="">
    <div id="people" class="people">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```js
const people = [{
    "name": "Messi",
    "age": 34
  },
  {
    "name": "Pedri",
    "age": 18
  },
  {
    "name": "Ronaldo",
    "age": 37
  }
];

function loadData() {
  people.forEach(function(person) {
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    $(container).addClass('person');

    const name = document.createElement('p');
    const age = document.createElement('p');

    $(name).addClass('name');
    $(age).addClass('age');

    name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(person["name"]));
    age.appendChild(document.createTextNode(person["age"]));

    container.appendChild(name);
    container.appendChild(age);

    document.getElementById('people').appendChild(container);
  })
}

function searchData(query) {
}

loadData();

window.onload = () => {
  const search = document.getElementById('search');
  search.onkeyup = () => {
    searchData(search.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input id="search" type="text" name="" value="">
    <div id="people" class="people">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use data attributes, for example `data-name` and `data-age`. You can attach these attributes to the container `div.person` in the following way:

```js
container.dataset.name = person["name"];
container.dataset.age = person["age"];
```

In `searchData()` you would first show all persons with `$('.person').show();` and then hide the persons that don't begins with the query string. For example:

```js
$('.person:not([data-name^="' + query + '"])').hide();
```

But you would only hide them if there is a search result. For example:

```js
if($('.person[data-name^="' + query + '"]').length != 0) {
    $('.person:not([data-name^="' + query + '"])').hide();
}
```

You could extend the function with `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()` to make the search case-insensitive:

```js
function searchData(query) {
  $('.person').show();
  
  if($('.person[data-name^="' + query.toLowerCase() + '"]').length != 0) {
    $('.person:not([data-name^="' + query.toLowerCase() + '"])').hide();
  }
  
  if($('.person[data-name^="' + query.toUpperCase() + '"]').length != 0) {
    $('.person:not([data-name^="' + query.toUpperCase() + '"])').hide();
  }
  
  if($('.person[data-age^="' + query + '"]').length != 0) {
    $('.person:not([data-age^="' + query + '"])').hide();
  }
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
const people = [{
    "name": "Messi",
    "age": 34
  },
  {
    "name": "Redri",
    "age": 18
  },
  {
    "name": "Ronaldo",
    "age": 37
  }
];

function loadData() {
  people.forEach(function(person) {
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.dataset.name = person["name"];
    container.dataset.age = person["age"];
    $(container).addClass('person');

    const name = document.createElement('p');
    const age = document.createElement('p');
    $(name).addClass('name');
    $(age).addClass('age');

    name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(person["name"]));
    age.appendChild(document.createTextNode(person["age"]));

    container.appendChild(name);
    container.appendChild(age);
    
  document.getElementById('people').appendChild(container);
  })
}

function searchData(query) {
  $('.person').show();
  
  if($('.person[data-name^="' + query.toLowerCase() + '"]').length != 0) {
    $('.person:not([data-name^="' + query.toLowerCase() + '"])').hide();
  }
  
  if($('.person[data-name^="' + query.toUpperCase() + '"]').length != 0) {
    $('.person:not([data-name^="' + query.toUpperCase() + '"])').hide();
  }
  
  if($('.person[data-age^="' + query + '"]').length != 0) {
    $('.person:not([data-age^="' + query + '"])').hide();
  }
}

loadData();

window.onload = () => {
  const search = document.getElementById('search');
  search.onkeyup = () => {
    searchData(search.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input id="search" type="text" name="" value="">
    <div id="people" class="people">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```